# blur() and keypress() not working on JQuery with replacewith()

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I use both blur() and keypress() events with replaceWith() in JQuery.
I tried this code below, it works with blur() without any error just fired a word 'undefined' but when I pressed enter key I got this error :

"Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'replaceChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is no longer a child of this node. Perhaps it was moved in a 'blur' event handler?"

This is my code:

```
$('body').on('blur keypress', 'input', function (e) {
  if (e.type === 'focusout' || e.keyCode === 13) {
    $(this).replaceWith('<strong>' + $(this).val() + '</strong>');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the enter key is pressed, the element loses focus, i.e. it blurs when it's removed, and triggers a new event, but when that fires, the element is no longer there, hence the error.

You could fix it by splitting the conditions, and just triggering the `blur` event when the enter key is pushed

```
$('body').on('blur keypress', 'input', function (e) {
  if ( e.type === 'focusout' ) {
    $(this).replaceWith('<strong>' + $(this).val() + '</strong>');
  }
  if ( e.keyCode === 13 ) {
    $(this).trigger('blur')
  }
});
```